# How to enable server side offline access for Chrome Extension OAuth?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am working on a Chrome extension where the backend server requires offline access and a refresh token for the user's account. I am not familiar with Chrome extensions, and not sure how I should do the authorization in this case.

The benefit of using `chrome.identity` is that I can set `interactive=false` and attempt to authorize without bothering the user when the plugin loads. However, the `getAuthToken()` method doesn't provide a way for the backend to get a refresh token.

If, instead, I use the `launchWebAuthFlow()` method and redirect user back to OAuth page, i.e.

```
 chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        url: https://*<my_host>*/auth/google,
        interactive: true,
  }, function(url) {
    var uri = URI(url),
        params = uri.search(true);
    var token = params.authToken;
    done(token);
  });
```

where `https://*<my_host>*/auth/google` is my server OAuth path, then for some reason the Permissions scope page doesn't show up.   Instead, it shows the Google login page. (Note: if I navigate to `https://*<my_host>*/auth/google` using the browser, it permissions page shows correctly.)

Is there anyway to do this with `chrome.identity` API?  If not, do I have to do the OAuth using a popup?  What's the proper way to do this normally?

Comment: Please include samples of your code.

Comment: Hey, How did you solve this problem?

Comment: Sadly, I didn't.  We stopped development on the plugin not long after.  Effectively, the best I could do was pre-populate the email address by suggesting the user.  It would still launch the authorization flow the same way.

Comment: I got it worked, the server side flow. I faced the similar problem as yours because the `client_secret` was not same for both the apps. The chrome app and the web  app registered on the developer console.

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677386/chrome-extension-needs-offline-access-from-server-side/36733744?noredirect=1#comment61064885_36733744