# chrome extension needs offline access from server side

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am building a chrome extension. I used  `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` to get the access_token. This provided me the access_token at the client side ( browser ) . Now I want to pass this access_token to my server.  I want to have offline access to granted APIs, I understand that for this I have to exchange it with the long-live-token and refresh token. Is there a secure way to pass access_token to server? Or should I use htttp post?

Another way is to redirect the user to server to have both the flow there.

What is the best and most secure practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sever side flow is best to obtain refresh_token using authorization_code flow.

Using the client side flow you cannot request refresh token , Google will reject that request   With the message **access_type offline, not allowed for response type token**

Once you obtain the access token and refresh token securely in server you could send that to chrome extension , so extension doesn't have to do any extra process in maintaining token, once the token is expired you could request the server for new access token, then server will use the refresh token to refresh the access token and send back to  the extension

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh , Wouldn't my server ip be open for all if I put that in Javascript code? How to handle that case?

Comment: It's domain , so it can be visible, one or the other way you will be communicating with your server , so the right problem to think about is , how to securely communicate with it

Comment: I think you are right. Any pointers for communicating securely? So if a user directly click on the domain , he will go to the oauth flow. Is that normal?

Comment: Yes , since the redirection happens in the extension , after getting the token , you could use cookie or page injection or some other form to send the data back to extension and for further communication you can use the access token to acces the data through api