# How to get refresh token in chrome extension using chrome.identity or nay other API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, access-token, refresh-token

I want refresh token in my chrome extension using chrome.identity.
i have tried gapi service and i am able to get refresh token using grantofflineaccess method, bot able to get it using chrome.identity.

Comment: Have you tried chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow instead of chrome.identity.getAuthToken ?

Comment: @LucasMendonca -- how would that change things?

Comment: according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677386/chrome-extension-needs-offline-access-from-server-side, it is either bad practice or impossible to request refresh token directly from the extension (i.e. using chrome.identity). Instead have a server requests both tokens for you, and forwards those tokens to the extension.